# Incorrect output for GCF calculator

Tags: java

My goal is to create a calculator that takes the user's input and determines factor pairs and the GCF. I'm trying to get my output to correspond with my professor and I am at a loss as to what could be incorrect. His required output is:

```
Enter the first number:
24
Enter the second number:
36
The factor pairs of 24 are: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24}.
The factor pairs of 36 are: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36}.
The greatest common factor (GCF) of 24 and 36 is 12.
```

however, my results are:

```
The factor pairs of 36 are: {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36}.
```

Then for the GCF for inputs 25, and 30 my results are:

```
The factor pairs of 25 are: {1, 5, 25}.
The factor pairs of 30 are: {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30}.
The greatest common factor (GCF) of 25 and 30 is 25.
```

but the required output is:

```
The greatest common factor (GCF) of 25 and 30 is 5.
```

Here is my code for processing the factor pairs and the GCF:

```
 public static void greatCF (Scanner sc){
    System.out.println("\nEnter the first number:");
      int num1 = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
      int num2 = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.print("The factor pairs of " + num1 + " are: {");
      for(int i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
        if (num1 % i == 0){
        System.out.print(i);  
        if (i < num1){
          System.out.print(", ");
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("}.");

      System.out.print("The factor pairs of " + num2 + " are: {");
      for(int j = 1; j <= num2; j++)
        if (num2 % j == 0){
        System.out.print(j);
        if (j < num2){
          System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("}.");

    int gcd = 1;
    for (int b = 1; b <= num1 &&  b <= num2; b++){
      if(num1 % b == 0 && num2 % b==0);
    gcd = b;
    }

    System.out.println("The greatest common factor (GCF) of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " + gcd + ".");
```

Comment: `if(num1 % b == 0 && num2 % b==0);` should not have the `;` at the end.

Comment: Wow was it that simple of a fix? Seems removing the ";" did the trick for the GCF result. Thank you. However, I still have the issue of the factor pairs not matching up.

Comment: What does the professor mean by "factor pairs"? Why not just say "factors" ?  Why does your professor have `6` twice in the output when the input is `36`? Why does your professor have `**` in front of the first `6` and in front of the `9` ?

Comment: Off topic: A better programming style would be to not duplicate the code for calculating the factors. Make that a method, and pass `num1` as an argument, and then again with `num2`.